# migration from Django1.3 to Django1.4 results in feincms drag-n-drop issue

Tags: django, mptt, feincms

With Django 1.3 I was using feincms and mptt very successfully.  I am finally getting around to updating to Django 1.4.1 plus the latest versions of feincms version 1.6.3 and mptt version 0.5.5 I am running into a problem where I have three items in the tree (a menu tree).  When I try to move a node to be a top level node but second in the list it ends up being first in the list. For example, if I have Page1, Page2, Page3 all as top level nodes and in that order in the tree, then I move Page3 with the feincms handle to be just under Page1 it ends up above Page1.  I can then move Page1 above Page3 (i.e. to the top of the list) and it goes there.  Has anybody else run into this?  Have I misconfigured something?  I've looked everywhere and can't find a misconfiguration.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have debugged the issue. The problem is caused by `fein_tree.js`. Moving a node around within the same tree level always detects its position as `left` while two other cases exists, namely a `first-child` or `last-child` scenario.

This derives from line 178 in the javascript file. It seems the javascript doesn't detect `last-child` positioning hence it doesn't seem to implement `first-child` detection at all.

I'll have to test some more to find a proper solution, and probably post a ticket at github

Comment: Thanks for the work Hedde, and for posting the ticket to github.  I'll track what is going on there.

Comment: This should now be fixed from 1.7.4+ (also for 1.6.5). See: https://github.com/feincms/feincms/issues/395